# Not able to move "Porto" theme top links under header content (After search) in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, header, toplinks, porto-theme

I am using Porto theme (header Type 1) with `Magento 2.3.2` setup.
I want to move Top Links section elements i.e : Sign in, Currency etc under the header content after the mini search bar.

Here is the code that I am using :

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
    <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="true" /> 

    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <container name="sign-in-div" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="signin-wrap" after="top.search">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link-custom" template="Magento_Theme::account/link/authorization.phtml" />
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```

1) The first line works fine, it removes the default one.
2) But the code under `"referenceContainer"` didn't work :(

I have tried the same code in Magento default setup and it works fine for me, but not with the `Porto theme`.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Check below file

```
/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/templates/html/header.phtml
```

check line No-**401** in that file if you want to add currency, header.links, and store_language directly copy code and paste it under header content.because of file **header.phtml** to handle the whole header section and all div also.

Hope this helps you...!